# Php Regular Expression Complex Matching

Tags: php, regex, url-routing

I'm working on a php mvc routing system and i need my router to be able to get the various parts of the url and map it accordingly like in this example:

```
url = controller/method/parameters/another/something/page/7
```

should map to:

```
controller = controller, method = method, parameters = parameters/another/something, page = 7
```

currently am only able to match

```
controller/method/parameter/page/7
```

with this regex:

```
{controller}/{method}/{parameters:[a-z0-9-]+}/page/{page:\d+}
```

which translates into this pattern:

```
/^(?P<controller>[a-z-]+)\/(?P<method>[a-z-]+)\/(?P<parameters>[a-z0-9-]+)\/page\/(?P<page>\d+)$/
```

I am using named captures to get the parts. i need help with the regex to use to get the result as stated above.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do this in PHP? If you're using it for rewriting URLs, you'd be better off with [.htaccess](/documentation/.htaccess/topics/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow `/`s in your parameter's character class.

```
/^(?P<controller>[a-z-]+)\/(?P<method>[a-z-]+)\/(?P<parameters>[a-z0-9\/-]+)\/page\/(?P<page>\d+)$/
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nX7cZ8/1

Comment: thanks for the answer, getting the desired results but there's a slight complication. how do i map this: `controller/method/parameters/another/something` without specifying the `page/7`.

Comment: sorry i fixed the above. i am actually looping through a set of rules formatted like the above rule but i want the expression to not parse `controller/method/parameter/another/page/7` as `controller = controller, method = method, parameter = parameter/another/page/7` but to invalidate or not match when the url has `page/7` in it. if i change the order of the routes in the routing table it works, but i don't want it that way, it has to be in all scenarios without the order affecting the matching.